# How to make a column header value into a date value and make the original value into it's own column named value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm using Python/ Pandas. I'm receiving output that is coming in this format where the actual date value is in the column header of the csv

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wp4kG.png)

I need it to be in this format where there is a column "date" and "value" that hold the data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBGtA.png)

I was trying to use Pandas but I'm not sure exactly how to transpose this csv

Comment: @Rabinzel no it doesn't that question is with making the column values into part of the column. I want to make parts of the column header that has a dynamic number of date such as 09/2022, 10/2022, 11/2022 into column values and make the original column values into another column called "value"

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can use the `melt` method of a DataFrame, by choosing which columns will remain, and which one have to be set as values

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'name': ['Profit', 'Loss'],
                             'Account Code': ['ABC', 'DEF'],
                             'Level Name': ['Winner', 'Loser'],
                             '01/2022': [100, 200],
                             '02/2022': [300, 400],
                             '03/2022': [500, 600]})

df2 = df.melt(id_vars=['name', 'Account Code', 'Level Name',],
              var_name="Date",
              value_name="Value").sort_values(by=['name', 'Account Code', 'Level Name',])
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This should produce your  desired outcome. Please let me know if  you need more clarification

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Profit', 'Loss'],
                   'Account Code':['ABC', 'DEF'],
                   'Level Name':['Winner', 'Loser'],
                   '01/2022':['100', '200'],
                   '02/2022':['300', '400']})

new_df_dict = {'Name':[],
               'Account Code' :[],
               'Level Name':[],
               'Value' : [],
               'Date':[]}

for i in range(len(df['Name'])):
    for date_ in df.columns.values[list(df.columns.values).index('Level Name')+1:]:
        new_df_dict['Name'].append(df['Name'][i])
        new_df_dict['Account Code'].append(df['Account Code'][i])
        new_df_dict['Level Name'].append(df['Name'][i])
        new_df_dict['Value'].append(df[date_][i])
        new_df_dict['Date'].append(date_)


for dt in range(len(new_df_dict['Date'])):
    new_df_dict['Date'][dt] = datetime.strptime(new_df_dict['Date'][dt], '%m/%Y')

new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_df_dict)
```

**You can use

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath)
```

to read in your data